# uploading a xlsx file to a specific path using java servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

i am new with servlet programming, i need to develop a `.WAR` API using servlet which will upload only xlsx files to a specific path in server (this API will be using by WebFocus (a programming language for reporting))

the specific path will be in a hidden filed of html `<form>`

here is my HTML

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="UploadServlet" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>

  <input type="hidden" name="path" value="G:/newFolder" />
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>  

</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

now what should write inside my `UploadServlet.java` file in order to upload xlsx files into path defined in path hidden filed

currently in my UploadServlet.java i used `MultipartRequest` and it uploads the file to destination correctly but i want the distenation to be the value of path hidden field of the `<form>`

```
import java.io.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  
import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;  

public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {  

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"g:/newFolder");  
out.print("successfully uploaded");  
}  
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where's your servlet code? That would be the relevant part of code.

Comment: i edited the Question and i added that @f1sh

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the path in your java code with the value of the submitted variable:

```
String uploadPath = request.getParameter("path");
MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, uploadPath);
```

Now your `MultipartRequest` gets initialized with the value from the hidden field.

Please note that this constructor of `MultipartRequest` [limits the upload size to 1 megabyte](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html#MultipartRequest%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: i did the same thing before but it returns null

Comment: Then your hidden field does not get submitted correctly. Try to print all the parameters that are in your request for inspection purposes.

Comment: i did, it says that you are trying to post non multipart data